# Simple if else php form script for select menu

Tags: php

Can you help me on creating a simple php script using select menu with if and else statement? 
I'm trying to create select menu that when i click the menu, it will redirect to another page.

Im really dumb in programming. I will be very grateful with your help. I'm hoping my statement is clear. Thanks in advance...

```
<td width="421">
    <label>
        <select name="journal" id="journal">
            <option value="IN PROGRESS">IN PROGRESS</option>
            <option value="PUBLISHED"></option>
            <option value="NOT APPLICABLE">NOT APPLICABLE</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</td>
```

Comment: php script for what?

Comment: php is only executed on the server. You would need to use javascript to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `php` for this unless you use a **form** to submit the select value to a php script, use `javascript` or `jquery` to achieve what you want, here's a jquery solution:

```js
jQuery(function () {
    $("#journal").change(function () {
    selectValue = $(this).val();
    if(selectValue == "IN PROGRESS"){
         location.href = "http://somesite.com";
    }else if( selectValue == "PUBLISHED"){
          location.href = "http://othersite.com";
    }else if( selectValue == "NOT APPLICABLE"){
         location.href = "http://anothersite.com";
       }
        })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td width="421">
    <label>
        <select name="journal" id="journal">
            <option value="">Choose Status</option>
            <option value="IN PROGRESS">IN PROGRESS</option>
            <option value="PUBLISHED">PUBLISHED</option>
            <option value="NOT APPLICABLE">NOT APPLICABLE</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</td>
```